# Why is this question considered a technical support request?

Tags: discussion

[NVIDIA SLI Power Supply Recommendation](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7135/nvidia-sli-power-supply-recommendation)

The OP is clearly asking for recommendations for their needs, it just so happens that their existing hardware will suffice.

Answer (score 4):

> will the existing PSU support is sufficient for 2 way SLI or should i upgrade my PSU

"Is my current PSU sufficient for what I'm planning to use it for" comes under the scope of technical support: it's asking us to use technical knowledge to provide a solution to a problem or an answer to an inquiry. Since it's not asking for a recommendation of hardware either, I closed it under that reason.